# I want a jsp named home.jsp to redirect to welcome jsp.It is not working.Please tell me where am I going wrong

Tags: jsp

I want a jsp named home.jsp to redirect to welcome jsp.It is not working.Please tell me where am I going wrong.There are three simple jsp below.Please help me out.I think there is some mistakes in connection to the database

```html
home.jsp-
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='login.jsp' method="post">
 <div>
  <table>
   <tr>
    <td>USERNAME</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="usernameID"/></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>PASSWORD</td>
    <td><input type="text" id=passwordID /></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="button" id="loginId" value="LOGIN" /></td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </div>

</form>

</body>
</html>
  
  
  login.jsp-
  <%@ page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<%
Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:8081:XE", "SYSTEM", "Lalita");


PreparedStatement ps=(PreparedStatement)con.createStatement();
String id=request.getParameter("usernameID");
String password=request.getParameter("passwordID");
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery("select * from USERCREDENTIALS");
String rsID=rs.getString(1);
String rsPassword=rs.getString(2);
out.println(rsID);
if(id==rsID && password==rsPassword )
 response.sendRedirect("./welcome.jsp");


%>
</body>
</html>
  
  
  
  welcome.jsp-
  <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory that you're trying to send redirect is wrong so
try this...

```
response.sendRedirect("../welcome.jsp");
```

This should work.

Comment: It still didn't work....please somebody guide.I really want to know where am i going wrong.

Comment: I am a bit confused that after clicking on login button how it would go to login.jsp,will be redirected just by form action???

Comment: ho I got it, you need to change the input type from **type="button"** to this **type="submit"**.